# Interfacing LCD via SPI

Tags: i2c, spi, esp8266, lcd, character-lcd

### Problem:

I am trying to figure out how to interface an LCD via SPI.

### What is known:

- It is 80x32 dot matrix.
- There are 23 pins on a flex cable.
- The pinout. I'll put it below. The LCD is marked with red on image.
- I've been told that the controller is sbn1661g.

LCD is from Motorola advisor pager, but I want to use it with esp8266. Any suggestions and critique counts since I am not a professional. Thanks a lot.

---

### LCD pinout

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPEAKER | ON | DISP_A0 |  |  | DISP_E1 | DISP_E2 |  | DB 0 | DB 1 | DB 2 | DB 3 | DB 4 | DB 5 | DB 6 | DB 7 | VDD | V5 | V3 | V2 | V4 | V1 | BACKPLANE |

[image: LCD pinout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LCD has no SPI compatible interface to connect to. Consider a GPIO expander with SPI or I2C bus to interface it, or maybe something more basic like serial to parallel shift register.